# angular $emit/$broadcast cross browser or client

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on angular and just found out that it allows me to do message passing by $emit / $boradcast.

I've tried doing something like

```
$rootscope.$emit('test', 'message');
```

And on another end i did

```
$rootscope.$on('test', function (event, data) {
    console.log(data); 
});
```

It works for a single browser. But lets say i have another browser that listen to the 'test', it doesn't fire anything across. Am i missing something or it doesn't work with cross browser?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what `$emit` and `$broadcast` are used for.  They are for one controller in your page to notify a different controller of change to your data; they are not for 2 instances of your app to communicate.

Comment: ahh my bad, so in another words there no way to use angular to communicate between two instances?

Comment: that's not a core feature of angular, no

Comment: do you have any in mind that can allow me to do that?

Comment: do I have any *what* in mind? frameworks? there are a few, but making recommendations isn't really acceptable here, as recommendations tend to be either too self serving or to be spam.

Comment: ahh are there any methods that i can contact you for the recommendations? From what i've discover, socket.io might fit my situation but i'm unsure are there any better solutions out there.

Comment: @daddyyee you probably need websockets (e.g. socket.io)

Comment: I've seen signalR, RabbitMQ, and Socket.io all used successfully in angular projects, but I'm not really an expert in that area to know which to use in which situations....

Comment: thanks a lot guys! I'll go and explore socket.io! really appreciated :D